# TypeORM enum does not detect the right param

Tags: typescript, graphql-js, typeorm

I have this enum:

```
enum ENUMIdentificationDocumentType {
    CC = "CÉDULA DE CIUDADANÍA",
    TI = "TARJETA DE IDENTIDAD"
}
```

So, when I do a request with Graphql through the schema, something like this:

```
mutation {
    register(
      ...Stuff
      identificationDocumentType: TI
      ...MoreStuff
    ) {
      path
      message
    }
}
```

And in the graphql schema the enum is defined like this:

```
enum ENUMIdentificationDocumentType {
    CC
    TI
}
```

So, the Mutation send me the data "identificationDocumentType" with TI, which is right... But the enum defined in the entity:

```
enum ENUMIdentificationDocumentType {
    CC = "CÉDULA DE CIUDADANÍA",
    TI = "TARJETA DE IDENTIDAD"
}
```

Does not recognize that the param TI should be "TARJETA DE IDENTIDAD", but it returns TI in the query:

```
INSERT INTO `user`(`id`, `routePhoto`, `routeCover`, `name`, `lastname`, `description`, `identificationDocumentType`, `identificationDocument`, `address`, `telephone`, `departament`, `city`, `civilStatus`, `website`, `gender`, `email`, `password`, `confirmed`, `forgotPasswordLocked`) VALUES (?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, ?, ?, DEFAULT, ?, ?, DEFAULT, ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, ?, ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: ["04ef7733-e4bd-4d00-a2f3-d455a58d7602","Andrés","Montoya","TI",991026077,"3213726060","andresmontoyafcb@gmail.com","$2a$10$G9JKoUxlxXYoND6iyws1Q.x2jbznKueoRorKqAGkTDTdaGUVAYlmu"]
```

How can I detect, when I send something like TI, the enum of TypeORM detects that is "TARJETA DE IDENTIDAD"?

This is the error from the console:

[image]

If someone need any little example, [here you go](https://uploadfiles.io/bdz8x).

You can run it giving permissions to the wait-for-it.sh file like this:

`chmod +x wait-for-it.sh`

And run it:

`docker-compose up --build`

Or check the db:

`docker-compose exec db mysql -u root -p`

Help please :(

Answer (score 0):

I think is a little too late but the error seems to be on the graphql schema enum since the values are automatically mapped to the name.

You can try graphql-js to map to a different value like so.

```
import {
  GraphQLEnumType,
} from 'graphql';

const taskStateEnumType = new GraphQLEnumType({
  name: 'TaskStateEnum',
  values: {
    ASSIGNED: {
      value: 0,
    },
    UNASSIGNED: {
      value: 1,
    },
    IN_PROGRESS: {
      value: 2,
    },
  },
});
```

For more information check this article.
https://medium.com/atheros/how-to-design-graphql-mutations-and-queries-part-2-enums-ebb01613832

And this.
[Do GraphQL enum types resolve their values automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367692/do-graphql-enum-types-resolve-their-values-automatically)