# How to return a value from DB to a enum type in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, enums, graphql, knex.js

In my Node app I'm using GraphQl and I had to build a function that from a DB using KenxJS return a result if a status PENDING or ANSWERED based on a condition.
That status in GraphQL is an enum type and I have difficulties to convert the result from my JS function to be an understandable enum type for GraphQL.

The enum type

```
enum ConversationStatus {
  PENDING
  RESOLVED
}
```

The function which has the result but in GraphQL give the error

```
"message": "Expected a value of type \"ConversationStatus\" but received: { status: \"ANSWERED\" }",
```

```
conversationStatus({ id }) {
    const status = this.tx(feedTableName)
      .select(feedColumns.status)
      .innerJoin(
        tableName,
        `${feedTableName}.${feedColumns.conversationId}`,
        `${tableName}.${columns.id}`
      )
      .where(feedColumns.conversationId, '=', id)
      .then(r => {
        if (r.some(e => e === 'PENDING_ANSWER')) {
          return {
            status: 'PENDING',
          };
        }
        return {
          status: 'ANSWERED',
        };
      });

    return status;
  }
```

The if checks if there is at least one result on DB as `PENDING_ANSWER` and I should return as a status `PENDING` and `RESOLVED` if false.

The `PENDING` and `RESOLVED` are enum types of GraphQL and I don't know how to return those in the right format to avoid the error as

```
status: PENDING or RESOLVED
```

Comment: why `return {
          status: 'ANSWERED',
        };` ?

Comment: I have to return 2 enums based if the results from db are pending answer true if are true then I have to return pending if are false resolved .  That the way but not fully sure is correct way

Comment: how returning `ANSWERED` is related to expected `PENDING` and `RESOLVED` ??

Comment: I have to return 2 enums based of the result from db. If pending answer is true then pending should be returned otherwise resolved. Probably I'm not doing it right but i don't know the way to return the 2 enums to graphQL

Comment: I answered and I do not understand so what value I need then. I need pending and resolved otherwise graphQL coplains about. I never used gql and don't know how to make that right. I know is complaining that I have to pass the enum and need a way to make it work

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62184442/6124657 (notice int return type for query, enums defined in js/ts and in graphql) and next answer (in the same thread) where you can return 0/1 and it will be mapped into enum

Comment: It is nice but do not resolve the fact I have somehow to relate the data from DB to PENDING and RESOLVED. Those examples uses only gql and no DB or else which could help me actually. I still have the same problem

Comment: start with return properly one of your enum types/values ... choosing one or another result will be a piece of cake after that

Comment: Whatever I'm doing is saying undefined for those enums in that way
My resolver which is related to the service I shared in my question
https://controlc.com/1a4b8ebb

Comment: hmm, try `status: ({ id }, _, ctx) => ConversationStatusEnum.PENDING` ... introduce service logic later

Comment: This just not do anything a part saying what was before 
"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Conversation.status.",
It is null as nothing is passed. The problem is how to relate what is the result from DB and return the right thing,

Comment: By the way `ConversationStatusEnum.PENDING` is undefined where I do cosole.log so I don't know how that should work

Comment: that's why you should start from working enum basics (graphql enum type != js/ts enum value) ... or drop using enum idea, define some dictinary, use ids, names, descriptions

Comment: Resolved the issue was the return as I had to return the string no the status part as per system configuration

Comment: I hope you don't `return 'ANSWERED';` ... field resolver must return only value matching field type .... there is nothing like 'status part' ... server (executor) 'collects' values for fields, attaches them to response [props] after type validation ... you were returning an object instead of enum value (1st problem, error was about) ... and wrong value `'ANSWERED'` (2nd problem) ... you can answer your question